# how to use a variable in jquery ui progressbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, variables, progress-bar

I wanna display a `progressbar` based of what the data- value of that wrapper `div` is.

```
<div class="photo webdesignTag" data-progress="20">
    <div class="photo-image"></div>
    <h2>Example1</h2>
    <div class="progressbar"></div>
</div>
<div class="photo photoshopTag" data-progress="50">
    <div class="photo-image"></div>
    <h2>Example2</h2>
    <div class="progressbar"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".photo").each(function() {
    var ProgressBarContainer = $(this).attr("data-progress");
    $(this).children("h2").html(ProgressBarContainer);
    $(this).children(".progressbar").progressbar({
        value: ProgressBarContainer
    });
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please describe what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you use `attr()` to get the `data-progress` value. This returns a string, whereas the `value` property is expecting an integer. If you retrieve the value using `data()` it will be correctly typed:

```
$(".photo").each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var progressBarValue = $el.data("progress");
    $el.children("h2").html(progressBarValue);
    $el.children(".progressbar").progressbar({
        value: progressBarValue
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/L5ps9upa/)